# delete rows in mysql database if selected time has passed

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete rows from the database once a set amount of time has passed and the code I have isn't working and I am not sure where I have gone wrong. I plan to change the amount of time to 1 month but it is currently 1 minute for testing purposes.

```
require 'core/init.php';

$remOld = "DELETE * FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratedate` < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE";

if ($remOld = $db->query($remOld)){
    echo ('records removed');
}else{
    echo ('didnt remove records');
}
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `(` before `NOW()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `*` from query and close open bracket in your query.

```
     DELETE  FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratedate` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Thankyou!! that worked, i am wondering why the * for all isn't needed now though?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html check correct usage of mysql delete,This will help you

Comment: @Parody Because the * is only needed in select commands (and a few others), when you want to select all rows.

Comment: @Parody,using delete ,We are deleting rows from the table,There is no role in *  or any set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$remOld = "DELETE FROM `ratings` WHERE `ratedate` < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 MINUTE'";

if ($remOld = $db->query($remOld)){
    echo ('records removed');
}else{
    echo ('didnt remove records');
}
```

Comment: i did and it didnt remove the applicable rows?